# Why isn't a call to overloaded function template ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, overload-resolution

Consider the following example. There are two function templates on lines marked `(1)` and `(2)` which get called on line `(3)`. Both templates match the call, and it seems that none of them is more specialized than the other.

```
#include <utility>

template <int V, bool Enabled = true>
struct Version;

template <int V>
std::true_type  Database(Version<V, V == 1>*);  // (1)

template <int V>
std::false_type Database(Version<V>*);          // (2)

using Winner = decltype(Database(std::declval<Version<1>*>()));  // (3)

int foo()
{
    return Winner::value;
}
```

Naturally, I would expect line (3) to produce an 'ambiguous call' error. But it doesn't. gcc 13.2, clang 15.0 and msvc v19.37 all select overload (2) with no error. Here's [godbolt online example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:72,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:72,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:72,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:72,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cint+V,+bool+Enabled+%3D+true%3E%0Astruct+Version%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cint+V%3E%0Astd::true_type++Database(Version%3CV,+V+%3D%3D+1%3E*)%3B++//+(1)%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cint+V%3E%0Astd::false_type+Database(Version%3CV%3E*)%3B++++++++++//+(2)%0A%0Ausing+Winner+%3D+decltype(Database(std::declval%3CVersion%3C1%3E*%3E()))%3B++//+(3)%0A%0Aint+foo()%0A%7B%0A++++return+Winner::value%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

The question is: **why? What am I missing in partial ordering and overload resolution?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Function_template_overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) is complicated, with transformation with Parameter/Argument.

```
template <int V>
std::true_type  Database(Version<V, V == 1>*);  // #1

template <int V>
std::false_type Database(Version<V>*);          // #2


Database(std::declval<Version<1>*>()); // deduction for #1 [V=1]
                                       // deduction for #2 [V=1] 
// partial ordering:
 

// #1 from #2: Version<V, B> from Version<U, true>: P1=V, A1=U: V=U
//                                            P2=B, A2=true: B=true OK
 
// #2 from #1: Version<V, true> from Version<U, B2>: P1=V A1=U: V=U
//                                             P2=true A2=B2: fails
 
// #2 is more specialized than #1
```

Comment: Why is `B` considered an independent parameter in '#1 from #2'? Isn't it a dependent expression which is evaluated to 'true' as soon as [V=1] is deduced for #1?

Comment: It is the first bullet of transformation: *"For each type, non-type, and template parameter, including parameter packs, (since C++11) a unique fictitious type, value, or template is generated and substituted into function type of the template"*. You might find example with `T, T*`, which becomes `U1, U2*`.

Comment: Yes, the substitution of a unique value gives `Version<U, true>`, where `U` is a unique value. But I don't see how deduction of `V` in `Version<V, V == 1>` from `Version<U, true>` is supposed to succeed. Putting `V = U`, that value is unique, so it's not equal to 1, and the resulting deduced type `Version<U, false>` is not identical to `Version<U, true>`.